# jqGrid treeGrid catch expand collaps events

Tags: jquery, cookies, jqgrid

I use jqGrid  to epose some big Tree. Now I want to remember expanded and collapsed nodes in cookies

So I want to catch expand and collaps event. I couldn't find it in manual

So I've resolved it in this way

```
grid.find("div.treeclick").bind("click",function(e){
    classes = $(this).attr('class');
    //returns:
    //ui-icon treeclick ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus
    //ui-icon treeclick ui-icon-triangle-1-e tree-plus
    if(classes.indexOf('-minus') != -1)
        alert ('Expand!');
    else if(classes.indexOf('-plus') != -1)
        alert ('Collaps!')
});
```

Could anybody propose another way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are currently no event or callback in the jqGrid which could help you to catch collapsing or expanding of the tree nodes.

In general the code which you posted do correct tests. Nevertheless you self are not full satisfied by the solution. I find it also not so good. The most problem which I see is that you test which icon has the button, but the icon will be changed by the original handler of the same events in the grid. The the order of the bindings should be very important.

On your place I prefer to use subclassing technique in such cases when no event exists. It's very easy, but it's 100% effective.

The Tree Grid has methods [expandNode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid#methods) and [collapseNode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid#methods) which are documented. The method will be called internally by jqGrid too in case of clicks on the node icon. The method `expandNode` calls `reloadGrid` to display the expanded tree.

So I suggest to add the following code after the Tree Grid is created:

```js
var orgExpandNode = $.fn.jqGrid.expandNode,
    orgCollapseNode = $.fn.jqGrid.collapseNode;
$.jgrid.extend({
    expandNode: function (rc) {
        alert('before expandNode: rowid="' + rc._id_ + '", name="' + rc.name + '"');
        return orgExpandNode.call(this, rc);
    },
    collapseNode: function (rc) {
        alert('before collapseNode: rowid="' + rc._id_ + '", name="' + rc.name + '"');
        return orgCollapseNode.call(this, rc);
    }
});
```

You can see the results on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree9.htm).

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports callbacks and events, which makes the above overwriting of `expandNode` and `collapseNode` unneeded. It supports already additional callbacks called before or after expanding or collapsing of nodes or rows. The names of callbacks: `treeGridBeforeExpandNode`, `treeGridAfterExpandNode`, `treeGridBeforeCollapseNode`, `treeGridAfterCollapseNode`, `treeGridBeforeExpandRow`, `treeGridAfterExpandRow`, `treeGridBeforeCollapseRow`, `treeGridAfterCollapseRow` and the corresponding jQuery Events `jqGridTreeGridBeforeExpandNode`, `jqGridTreeGridAfterExpandNode`, `jqGridTreeGridBeforeCollapseNode`, `jqGridTreeGridAfterCollapseNode`, `jqGridTreeGridBeforeExpandRow`, `jqGridTreeGridAfterExpandRow`, `jqGridTreeGridBeforeCollapseRow`, `jqGridTreeGridAfterCollapseRow`. All callbacks has one parameter: `options`, which has two properties: `rowid` and `item`. The `item` is the node, which will be expanding/collapsing.

Comment: @gv0zd: You are welcome! I will post the suggestion to introduce `beforeExpandNode` and `boforeCollapseNode` as the feature request in [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/). Hopefully it will be included in the next release of jaGrid.

Comment: @RafikHaceb: You are welcome! Free jqGrid has already many callbacks, which one can use. No overwriting of `expandNode` and `collapseNode` is required now. You can try to use the callbacks `treeGridBeforeExpandNode`, `treeGridAfterExpandNode`, `treeGridBeforeCollapseNode`, `treeGridAfterCollapseNode`, `treeGridBeforeExpandRow`, `treeGridAfterExpandRow`, `treeGridBeforeCollapseRow`, `treeGridAfterCollapseRow` or the events (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L2050-L2058)). All the callbacks has one parameter `options` with many properties.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162847/how-to-prevent-row-selection-on-tree-mode-node-collapse-in-free-jqgrid