# Is it possible to use the built in multiselect functionality in jqGrid TreeGrids?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I use the [jqGrid TreeGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid) functionality. Is it possible to use the [multiselect functionality](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/selection/multiselect/default.php) with TreeGrid? If not, is there a workaround for this?

I would like to have something like when the top level is checked/unchecked and sub level is open all sub levels should be checked/uncheked automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create additional column having `formatter:'checkbox'` with `formatoptions:{disabled: false}` and simulate the multiselect functionality in your own code. You can see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree6.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210627/315935) as the starting point. The usage of [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) could be probably also helpful for you. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181899/315935) could help you to do some additional actions on expanding of nodes.