# Intercept the cellSubmit jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to intercept the cellSubmit for a specific cell in jqGrid.   I would like to override it in such a way that It allows me to handle my own submit using custom code.
But I only want to do this on a specific cell.  The rest of the cells I would like to allow it to submit through jqGrids build in submit mechanisms.  Is this possible?  I've been going circles trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your requirements in different way. If you just need to send **custom data** or **custom serialized data** in some cases it would be enough to use `serializeCellData` callback. Probably `beforeSaveCell`, `beforeSubmitCell` or `afterSaveCell` can be also helpful.

Alternatively you can "subclass" `saveCell` function (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482049/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181899/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230794/315935) as examples). The corresponding code could be like the following

```
var orgSaveCell = $.fn.jqGrid.saveCell;

$.jgrid.extend({
    saveCell: function (iRow, iCol) {
         var res;

         // make some tests and do your own implementation of saveCell
         // or call the original one
         res = orgSaveCell.call (this, iRow, iCol);

         // As one more option you can do some modification or do
         // additional actions before calling of original saveCell
         // or after it

         return res;
    }
});
```