# How to convert point to comma for any number of decimal places

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, localization, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid data comes as json string from server.
It  can contain different number of decimal places like

```
amount: "300.1", 
tax: "20.12", 
total: "320.123"
```

This data should appear as comma separated in jqgrid columns like

```
300,1    20,12    320,123
```

Locale file grid.locale-et.js was created for this with contents

```
formatter: {
    integer: {
        thousandsSeparator: " ",
        defaultValue: "0"
    },
    number: {
        decimalSeparator: ",",
        thousandsSeparator: " ",
        decimalPlaces: 2,
        defaultValue: "0,00"
    },
```

and `template: 'number'`  option in colmodel is used. This shows all columns with 2 digits like

```
300,10    20,12    320,12
```

How to fix this so that columns will display proper numbers of decimal places?

I tried in colmodel

```
"template":"number",
"decimalPlaces":4
```

but it still shows 2 decimal places.
Without using template proper number of decimal places is shown.

Testcase is at  http://jsfiddle.net/xssnr1gn/3/

It contains

```
 { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.1", tax: "20.12", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.123" },
```

but output is 2 decimal places for every column.

**Update**

If `decimalPlaces: 2,` is removed, jqgrid looks like

[image: removed]

Issues:

1. decimal separator is changed to .
2. There are variable number of decimal places
3. The is  non-understandable value  `7 146 2.8`
4. for some numbers space appears before decimal point

Data from server contains fixed number of decimal places. How to show exactly the same number of decimal places as it is in server data ?

Comment: What happens if you leave out `decimalPlaces: 2,` from the number formatter?

Comment: I updated question and described result if it is leaved out.

Comment: Mmm, not simple then. I'm guessing you need a [Custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xssnr1gn/4/

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

You need to apply the formatter and formatoptions

```
formatter: "number", formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 4, defaultValue: '0.0000'}
```

And full code:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
            { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
            { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.1", tax: "20.12", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.123" },
            { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4 test4 test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9 test9 test9 test9 test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
            { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
            { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
        ],
        $grid = $("#list"),
        initDateEdit = function (elem) {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                autoSize: true,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeek: true
            });
        },
        initDateSearch = function (elem) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                initDateEdit(elem);
            }, 50);
        };

    $grid.jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        colNames: ["", "Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "act", template: "actions" },
            { name: "name", align: "center", width: 100, editrules: {required: true} },
            { name: "invdate", width: 82, align: "center", sorttype: "date", frozen: true,
             formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true }, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
             editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },            
             searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
            { name: "amount", width: 62, template: "number",
             formatter: "number", formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 4, defaultValue: '0.0000'},
               editoptions: {
                   type: "number", 
                   step: "0.01",
                   min: "0.00",
                   max: "1000",
                   pattern: "[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?",
                   title: "This should be a number with up to 2 decimal places."
               } },
            { name: "tax", width: 45, template: "number", autoResizableMinColSize: 40 },
            { name: "total", width: 53, template: "number" },
            { name: "closed", width: 60, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
            { name: "ship_via", width: 76, align: "center", formatter: "select",
             edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
             stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
            { name: "note", width: 43, edittype: "textarea", sortable: false }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        pager: true,
        sortname: "invdate",
        sortorder: "desc",
        searching: { defaultSearch: "cn", searchOperators: true }
    })
        .jqGrid("filterToolbar")
        .jqGrid("gridResize");
});
```

Comment: This assumes that all rows in column have same number of decimal places. If amount column has different number of decimal places in diferent rows, it fails. For example http://jsfiddle.net/3xoLrkk4/1/   does not show amount column according to source data. How to fix this so that variable number of decimal places are shown in single column ?

Comment: This also does not restrict maximum number on manual entry. I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853914/how-to-restrict-max-value-on-html5-number-input-on-manual-entry How to fix ?