# How to restrict max value on html5 number input on manual entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid column is defined to use html5 number input type like

```
{ name: "amount", width: 62, template: "number",
             formatter: "number", formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:",", thousandsSeparator: " ", decimalPlaces: 4, defaultValue: '0.0000'},
               editoptions: {
                   maxlength; 4
                   type: "number", 
                   max: 9999
               } },
```

It allows to enter numbers from keyboard greater than 9999.
`max: 9999` affects only to entry using spinner.

How to fix this so that keyboard entry cannot exceed 9999 ?

testcase is at

http://jsfiddle.net/jhckz7rr/3/

It allows to manually enter numbers greater that 9999 into Amount column. How to restrict manual entry to 9999 ?
I tried also to use string max value `max: '9999'` but problem persists.

[image: big]

If input type is text, input respects maxlength value.

Comment: Could you check if the actual input has properties you've put there? I mean ``maxlength`` and ``max``.
I suppose it doesn't

Comment: jqgrid creates input element if edit button is pressed and should create input element with those attributes `input type=number max=9999 maxlength=4`.  Input element is created on the fly.

Comment: Do you get the results using UP and DOWN buttons or by direct input of the value 9999?

Comment: This occurs if 99999 is entered from keyboard. Pressing up button restricts max value properly

Comment: @Andrus: It's what I tried to explain you in my last answer: `<input type="number" ... />` looks good only if one don't go in details. If you do look at details you will see that you have to use the same old JavaScript tricks and the usage of `<input type="number" ... />` could just make the illusion of solving the problem. I still think that the control can be very helpful in single language environment. The main problem of it is missing locale support. Thus I think it's not exceptable for enterprise and multi-language web solutions.

Comment: using `input type=text` for number input requires creating and maintaining numeric keypad for touch devices and suppress alphabetic default keypad. This is more work than using `input type=number` which supports this natively. Issue in question can probably be solved by calling field Validate() method before save or using custom `pattern` attribute. How to activate numeric touch keypad for number input ? If this is possible, input type=text can used

Comment: @Andrus: You should write `@Oleg` in your comment if more as one person posted comments. I could read your comment only accidentally. I see no problem in solving the issue with entering of long values, you should just use old JavaScript methods like `mask` or just by `keydown`. In other words `max` attribute helps you here not really and you have to use solutions based on any `type` value. I wrote that *I see the only problem in localization*. The person who opens your application in ipad/mobile device with OS/web browser in another language will see and save other value as decimal separator.

Comment: @Oleg `input type=number` has native html5 validate method which validates keyboard entry also. In regular form this is called on clicking submit button and sumbit is cancelled automatically. How to force jqgrid to call this method if save button is pressed and cancel save if validation fails ?

Comment: @Andrus: I know only `.checkValidity()` method which can be called on the DOM element of `<input>`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation_API) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-cva-checkvalidity) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like the following

```
{
    name: "amount",
    width: 62,
    template: "number", // formatter: "number"
    formatoptions: {
        decimalSeparator: ",",
        thousandsSeparator: " ",
        decimalPlaces: 2,
        defaultValue: "0,00"
    },
    editoptions: {
        maxlength: 7,
        type: "number",
        max: "9999",
        dataEvents: [
            {
                type: "blur",
                fn: function (e) {
                        if (e.target.checkValidity()) {
                            $(e.target).removeClass("ui-state-error");
                        } else {
                            $(e.target).addClass("ui-state-error");
                            alert(e.target.validationMessage);
                            $(e.target).focus();
                        }
                    }
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

The above code calls `checkValidity()` method of `<input type="number">`. Of cause you need to include additional tests in the code like validation that `e.target.checkValidity` is a function (for the case of executing in old web browser) and some other. The above code just shows the main idea of validation which uses functionality of `<input type="number">`.

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jhckz7rr/8/, which works for both inline editing and form editing.

Comment: I added line `$.extend(true,$.jgrid.inlineEdit, {keys: true } );` to this demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ggsyagov/1/. Entering big number and pressing enter saves invalid value without any message. Also cancel button cannot clicked. How to fix those issues? Maybe this validation should built-in into jqgrid before every save. Since this blocks cancel buttons using blur without checking for cancel clikc looks unreasonable.

Comment: @Andrus: No. The current validation implemented in jqGrid and free jqGrid is validation which work **after the data read from input controls**. It's independent from any API provided by controls. You can still easy use existing callbacks like `beforeSaveRow` for example to call `checkValidity()` in the same way and return `false` from the callback if you decide to stop saving.

Comment: Since this code blocks cancel button it looks like it is not usable. Should beforeSaveRow check for every control validaty before saving data ? How to loop over controls in beforeSaveRow ?

Comment: @Andrus: There are many ways to enumerate controls. `beforeSaveRow` have `rowid` parameter. You can just search for all `input[type=number]` in the row: `$("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)).find("input[type=number]")`. Another way are based on the id names of controls: `rowid + "_" + columnName`. You can enumerate all columns of `colModel` get the controls by ids.

Comment: Will beforeSaveRow work in both inline and form edit and append modes and in cell edit mode? Probably it needs to be called for input type=date also. Is there some sample available?

Comment: @Andrus: `beforeSaveRow` is inline editing callback. I try to hold the compatibility to the previous (old) versions of jqGrid. The names of callbacks of form editing are other. In general on can use `.find("input[type=date]")` in the same way like `type=number`

Comment: Will this require implementing of 3 different methods: one for inline add/edit, second for form add/edit and third for cell editing mode for single cell ?

Comment: @Andrus: **Typical an application uses only one editing mode.** If I would implement support of some new feature of editing, then I would have to do it (at least test it) in all three editing modes and probably in two searching modes too. It's the difference.

Comment: I added this as possible enhancement to https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/178

Answer (score 0):

Create validation on input with jQuery.

Event listeners are attached on edit click, and removed on save click.
I used setTimeout, to be synchronized with free-jqgrid elements manipulation - as the proper solution will be to extend free-jqgrid functionality

```
function restrictMax(){

    var max = parseFloat($(this).attr('max'))
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val())
    if($(this).val() > max){
        $(this).val(max)
    }
}
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.fa-pencil').click(function(){ //click on edit
        var thatParent = $(this).closest('tr')
        setTimeout(function(){

            thatParent.find('input[type="number"]').on('input',restrictMax)
        },0);
    })
    $('.fa-floppy-o').click(function(){ //click on save
        var thatParent = $(this).closest('tr')
        setTimeout(function(){
            thatParent.find('input[type="number"]').off('input',restrictMax)
        },0)
    })

},0)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhckz7rr/6/

Comment: This is additional code to maintain. For normal forms input type=number restricts keyboard max value also. There should be some simple fix to force  input from keyboard to restrict it also in jqgrid

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules
JQGrid has way to apply error classes. You still have to validate the data server side.

Comment: @Oleg input type=number has native html5 validate method which validates keyboard entry. In regular form this is called on clicking submit button and sumbit is cancelled. How to force jqgrid to call this method if save button sis pressed and cancel save if validation fails ?