# How to avoid date corruption pressing save button in free jqgrid inline edit

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, datepicker, jqgrid-formatter, free-jqgrid

Native html date picker using code from [How to use input type='date' for date column in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040738/how-to-use-input-type-date-for-date-column-in-jqgrid) is used for date field editing in free jqgrid.
Saving row using toolbar date buttons corrupts date value.

Steps to reproduce:

- Open page below in Chrome
- Click in first row to edit it
- Press Save button in toolbar

Observed: 29.03.2037 date appears.

Expected: Date should keep its value, 31.10.2007

How to fix this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/26040738/315935</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        /*global $,Modernizr */
        /*jslint browser: true, unparam: true */
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    { id: "10",  invdate: "", name: "test1",  note: "note1",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" }
                ],
                $grid = $("#list"),
                initDateEdit = function (elem, options) {
                    // we need get the value before changing the type
                    var orgValue = $(elem).val(), newformat,
                        cm = $(this).jqGrid("getColProp", options.name);

                    $(elem).attr("type", "date");
                    if ((Modernizr && !Modernizr.inputtypes.date) || $(elem).prop("type") !== "date") {
                        // if type="date" is not supported call jQuery UI datepicker
                        $(elem).css({ width: "8em" }).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
                            autoSize: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    } else {
                        // convert date to ISO
                        if (orgValue !== "") {
                            //newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                            //    cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                            //    $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat");
newformat="d.m.Y";
                            $(elem).val($.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, newformat, orgValue, "Y-m-d"));
                        }
                        // "10em" is better for Chrome and "11em" for Opera 24
                        $(elem).css("width", /OPR/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "11em" : "10em");
                    }
                },
                myBeforeSaveRow = function (options, rowid) {
                    var $self = $(this), $dates = $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)).find("input[type=date]");
                    $dates.each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this), newformat, str,
                            id = $this.attr("id"),
                            colName = id.substr(rowid.length + 1),
                            cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", colName);
                        if ((Modernizr && Modernizr.inputtypes.date) || $this.prop("type") === "date") {
                            // convert from iso to newformat
                            str = $this.val();
                            if (str !== "") {
                                //newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                                //    cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                                //    $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat");
newformat="d.m.Y";

                                str = $.jgrid.parseDate.call($self[0], "Y-m-d", str, newformat);
                            }
                            $this.attr("type", "text");
                            $this.val(str);
                        }
                    });
                },
                initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                            autoSize: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showWeek: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true
                        });
                    }, 50);
                },
                numberTemplate = {formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
                    editrules: {number: true, required: true},
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"] }};

            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
//loadComplete: function() {
//    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
//},
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes", "Tax", "Amount", "Total"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "name", align: "center", editable: true, width: 65, editrules: {required: true} },
                    { name: "invdate", width: 125, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                        formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d.m.Y"}, editable: true,
                        editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                    { name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",
                        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } },
                    { name: "ship_via", width: 105, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "select",
                        edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                    { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea" },
                    { name: "tax", width: 52, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "amount", width: 75, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "total", width: 60, template: numberTemplate }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                pager: "#pager",
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                sortname: "invdate",
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                height: "auto",
                rownumbers: true,
                editurl: "clientArray",
//editurl: "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/test",
        toppager: true,

                onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                    var $self = $(this),
                        savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                    if (savedRow.length > 0) {
                        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
                    }
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, {
                        keys: true,
                        beforeSaveRow: myBeforeSaveRow
                    });
                }
            });

    $.extend(true,$.jgrid.edit, {
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        navkeys: [true,33,34],
        savekey: [true, 13],
        recreateForm: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        left: 10,
        top: 15,
        dataheight: '100%',
        width: window.innerWidth - 18
    });



        $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#list_toppager", {
edit: true
});

        $grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#list_toppager', {
edit: true
});


        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code, which you posted, have two small problems:

1. you use wrong option of jQuery UI Datepicker. `dateFormat: "d.m.Y"` should be fixed to `dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"`.
2. you should use `beforeSaveRow: myBeforeSaveRow` **in all inline editing**. The current code uses if only is case of starting editing by direct call of `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow`.

I suggest you to use `inlineEditing` option of free jqGrid:

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var $self = $(this),
        savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
    if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
    }
    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
},
inlineEditing: {
    // if defines COMMON inline editing options
    keys: true,
    beforeSaveRow: myBeforeSaveRow
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/dateInputInline48.htm).

Comment: Thank you. I used `$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
            keys: true,
            beforeSaveRow: myBeforeSaveRow, ... })
` . Is This OK ? Can `$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit` used as single place to pass parameters to 3 all methods (action button,toolbar button, calling editRow on row click)  which can used to start inline editing? Will it pass   myBeforeSaveRow to form editing also or will form editing still require separate method ?

Comment: @Andrus: I made more changes in the code of **free jqGrid**. Now you should don't need to use `beforeSaveRow: myBeforeSaveRow` more. Free jqGrid do all work internally it the `<input>` have `type="date"`. See  [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29197989/315935). In general one can use `$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, {...})` to set default options **to all grids**. The option `inlineEditing: {...}` is practical to set inline editing option *to one grid*.