# JQGrid remove error model popup

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, validation

I am using JQGrid edit rules to validated data in JQGrid cell. Now, it is showing model pop-up if error in input data and not allowed to add row. I want all functionality other than model popup. I want to show error in custom error div on page only. I don't want model pop-up. But again all other things should be same only, like in case of error row should not be added. Here is the [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules)  of all the editrules I am using. I am using default one and couple of custom functions. All rules are working as required.

Please let me know if any further information needed.

Comment: Which editing mode you use: form editing or inline editing?

Comment: @Oleg inline editing. with support of bulk add and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline editing don't support currently any other validation message as popup dialog. I agree that it's a problem, but I can't provide any *common* good solution for you.

What you can do for example is overwriting (subclass) the original `$.jgrid.info_dialog` to your custom implementation (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230794/315935) for an example of such trick). Then you can validate based on input parameters of `$.jgrid.info_dialog` whether it is calling to display validation error of inline editing or not. In case of validation error you can place the error message on your custom div. In all other cases you can forward the call to the original `$.jgrid.info_dialog`.

Comment: I ll check it out, if I stuck I ll let you know. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I have to changed source file for that. One more thing, is there anyway I can skip dialog only. Means how much I have to customized if I like to by pass edit rule all together, and introduce custom edit rules?