# jqgrid info dialog function onClose

Tags: jqgrid

i am showing the server error message with an info_dialog.
I would like to fire a function, when the info_dialog ist getting closed. I have tried to do it with a mouse click, but it only fires after the dialog is already closed

first mouseclick: dialog closes, but alert is not fired

second and every following mouseclick: alert is fired.

I am using celledit.
Anyone with an idea how i can fire a function, when the dialog ist getting closed?
Thanks for your help.

```
errorCell:  function(serverresponse, status) {

    $.jgrid.info_dialog(
    $.jgrid.errors.errcap,
    serverresponse.responseText,
    $.jgrid.edit.bClose,
    { zIndex: 1500}
    );


    $(document).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `$.jgrid.info_dialog` supports `onClose` callback which will be called on closing. The return value from the callback informs whether the closing is permitted. Just try the code

```js
$.jgrid.info_dialog(
    $.jgrid.errors.errcap,
    serverresponse.responseText,
    $.jgrid.edit.bClose,
    {
        zIndex: 1500,
        onClose: function () {
            alert("inside onClose");
            return true; // allow closing
        }
    }
);
```

**UPDATED**: To catch closing of `$.jgrid.info_dialog` in case of clicking with the mouse **outside** of the dialog one have to do more complex trick.

```js
var orgViewModal = $.jgrid.viewModal;
$.extend($.jgrid,{
    viewModal: function (selector, options) {
        if (options.onHide) {
            options.orgOnHide = options.onHide;
            options.onHide = function (h) {
                alert("inside onHide");
                return options.orgOnHide.call(this, h);
            }
        }
        return orgViewModal.call (this, selector, options);
    }
});

$.jgrid.info_dialog($.jgrid.errors.errcap, "Test message",$.jgrid.edit.bClose, {
    zIndex: 1500,
    onClose: function () {
        alert("inside onClose");
        return true; // allow closing
    }
});
```

In the first part of the code I use "subclassing" of `$.jgrid.viewModal` method (like I used in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181899/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230794/315935) and some other). So I forward all calls to original `$.jgrid.viewModal` method with one exception. If `$.jgrid.viewModal` method are called with `onHide` callback parameter I forward to original `$.jgrid.viewModal` method modified implementation of the callback. It allows to catch closing of the dialog.

**UPDATED 2**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/info_dialog_onClosing.htm) shows the approach live.

Alternatively (instead of subclassing) you can just modify [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.common.js#L257-L260)

```js
onHide: function(h) {
    h.w.hide().remove();
    if(h.o) { h.o.remove(); }
},
```

of `info_dialog` in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. You need just insert additional call of `mopt.onClose` if the option defined. Probably one should include **additional** callback `onClosed` because `onClose` can deny closing, but new callback called inside of `onHide` can't do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, this event only fires when i click on the close button, but not when i click anywhere else with mouse and the dialog closes. I am now showing the error in a div.

Comment: Thanks for your work you invest to help me!
When the info_dialog is opening the first time, the closing is work like a charm. When the info_dialog opens a second time, i am unable to close it. The alerts are coming, but the window is not closing. I am getting 762 alerts. (Changed alert to console.log to get the number).

Comment: @user3229474: I appended my answer with **UPDATED 2** part.

Comment: I have now added the $.extend function as normal javscript code and only the $.jqgrid.info_dialog to the errorcell event. I think it is working now! Before i had both functions in the errorcell event. Thank you for your help in this question and also for answering all the questions of the other people, it helped me a lot!