# How can I hide rows in jqGrid treegrid, triggered after the expandNode event?

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I have a basic treegrid with 2 levels, and I want some rows hidden and others visible; I do this with $("#" + rowId).hide() and $("#" + rowId).show() programatically, as which rows are visible is dependent on data outside the grid. That part works fine.

However, when I collapse a node and then expand it, all children are visible, even those I hid. Evidently, jqGrid is pretty much just doing .hide() and .show() on the rows, which negates my settings. So my thought is to add a hidden field in each row that stores whether it should be visible or not, and then re-hide/show after the expand event. The problem is, I'm not sure how to catch the event and execute code immediately after it.

Oleg shows a method for catching the events here: [jqGrid treeGrid catch expand collaps events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178682/jqgrid-treegrid-catch-expand-collaps-events)

Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me because it will just override whatever hide/show I do there. I need to execute code after the jqGrid functions. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seems very easy for me. One need just make small modification from the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9181899/315935) which you reference. You can do something like the following

```js
var orgExpandNode = $.fn.jqGrid.expandNode;
$.jgrid.extend({
    expandNode: function (rc) {
        // here you can insert the code which will be executed
        // before the original expandNode
        var res = orgExpandNode.call(this, rc);

        // now you can execute some code after the original expandNode
        // for example the next line hide the node in the grid
        $("#1_1_1").hide(); // hide some row of the grid

        return res; // return the value from expandNode
    }
});
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HoldRowHidden.htm). The demo has one node in the TreeGrid which has `id="1_1_1"`, but it stay hidden all the time.

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) have `beforeExpandRow`, `afterExpandRow`, `beforeExpandNode` and `afterExpandNode` callbacks and `"jqGridTreeGridBeforeExpandRow"`, `"jqGridTreeGridAfterExpandRow"`, `"jqGridTreeGridBeforeExpandNode"`, `"jqGridTreeGridAfterExpandNode"` events. Thus subclassing of TreeGrid methods described above is not required in case of usage free jqGrid.

Comment: Wow, I almost feel a little silly for not thinking of this. Worked great.